# Visual C++: Cannot open include file

Tags: c++, header

I'm new here, so hello world!

I'm working on a big project in C++.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate RC.

I got 2 projects in same solution:

MyProgram and MyProgram.Input
It is something like that:

Mouse.h in MyProgram.Input:

```
#include "SDL.h"

class Mouse
{
public:
    int x, y;
    void Update();
}

Mouse::Update()
{
SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
}
```

MyProgram.Input has included SDL2 and it compiles fine!

So I included MyProgram.Input to MyProgram.
MyProgram is console application, when I include "Mouse.h" to MyProgram and compile it I got this error: Cannot find include file: "SDL.h"

I want to get mouse input from MyProgram.Input in my console in MyProgram project.

SDL.h is file from MyProgram.Input, not from MyProgram!

Comment: Looks like you need to tell the `MyProgram` application the location of the `SDL.h` file.

Comment: Could you tell me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't refer to .h include by project but by path on drive. You need to create a common folder for all includes of you projects, move you current .h to it and all new .h will be added to it, this must has a relation to the solution path and go to the project that you need to include file from this folder and open its properties and add include directory that is something like $(SolutionDir)\Includes , where Includes is the directory to include .h files. Now you can include it in multiple projects, we use this way.

Alternative way is to use real path like

```
#include "../MyProgram.Input/SDL.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to **MyProgram**'s properties, choose C/C++ and at *"Additional Include Directories"* set it (or add to it) the path from **MyProgram.Input** where *SDL.h* is located. (you should use relative paths).